# SQL Server statistic for a multi index incorrect when using NULL in a date column

Tags: sql-server, database-indexes

SQL Server has a statistic on an index which is estimating the number of rows incorrectly, this table (and predicates) are used from a lot of different queries. This causes these queries to perform poorly as the statistic expects the query to return 5 rows, whereas it returns 431268.

The query:

```
SELECT COUNT(BuildRecord.BuildRecordID)
FROM dbo.BuildRecord
WHERE BuildRecord.ContainedToDT IS NULL
  AND BuildRecord.RfBuildRecordTypeID = 2 
  AND BuildRecord.IsEdited = 0
```

[image: Execution Plan]

The statistic was updated with a FULLSCAN yesterday:

[image: Statistics for the index]

The index has <1% fragmentation.

In the `BuildRecord` table, the `ContainedToDT` is a NULLABLE `DATETIMEOFFSET`, `RfBuildRecordTypeID` is a NOT-NULL `SMALLINT` and `IsEdited` is a NOT-NULL `TINYINT`.

The index is as follows:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IM_ContainedToDT_RfBuildRecordTypeID_IsEdited] 
ON [dbo].[BuildRecord] ([ContainedToDT] ASC, [RfBuildRecordTypeID] ASC, [IsEdited] ASC)
INCLUDE([InvPackCreatedID], [InvPackConsumedID]) 
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
             SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

SQL Server version is Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU8) (KB4577194)
Compatibility mode is SQL Server 2016 (130)

Any suggestions or thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the compatability mode to SQL Server 2019 (150) seems to give me a better estimatation for this statistic.

[image: Execution plan in compatability mode 2019]

Forcing the query to use Legacy Cardinality Estimation
[image: Legacy Cardinality Estimation]

Comment: 2019 seems to give better performance due to presumably estimated rows and plan going parallel; have you tried forcing legacy cardinality estimator in 2016 compatability?

Comment: Thanks Stu, the execution plan using the FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION hint looks a lot more similar to the 2019 execution plan. Added it to the post above

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder if there might be a bug with using 2019 in 2016 compat mode, I wonder what would happen on sql2016, might be handy to compare. 2919 has had more issues than you'd have hoped!